# Eigen::Vector template class?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen

If I want to statically allocate a vector using the `Eigen` library I can simply use

`Eigen::Matrix<double, kNumStates, 1> vec;`

but I can't seem to find something of the form

`Eigen::Vector<double, kNumStates> vec;`

which feels more intuitive. I was wondering if there's any background as to why an `Eigen::Vector` template class wasn't implemented. Simply for code readability, it would be kinda nice to have such a class available.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, matrices and vectors use the same class template, since a vector mathematically behaves like a matrix with just one column.

In the master branch (and the upcoming 3.4 version) there is an alias template

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
using Vector = Matrix<Type, Size, 1>;
```

So with C++11 or later you can actually write

```
Eigen::Vector<double, kNumStates> vec;
```